# Exchange Server "All Contacts" DistinguishedFolderId (copy from StackExchange)

Tags: exchange

I need to retrieve contacts from Exchange server global address book using this SOAP request

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566107%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

How can I get DistinguishedFolderId for Exchange "All Contacts" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global Address Book has't DistinguishedFolderId because it is a AD not Exchange object.